# Make JFrame / JPanel unclickable

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame with an associated JPanel which fill the screen, both having `setFocusable(false)` and in Front another JFrame with a Jpanel with a fixed size and centered (both are unmoveable). In this 'front' Panel theres a game, but when i click on the background Frame the front Panel moves to the background i only see the (dark grey) background Panel.

This is very annoying as you can imagine and i guess there must be a simple solution (i thought the setFocusable(false) would do the trick) but i simply cannot find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [JFrame.setAlwaysOnTop( true )](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29)

Comment: nope - and works fine, thank you! Is there something similar to keep focus? Like keylisteners dont react when i click away

Comment: Yes, use the GlassPane http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane

Comment: @Samuel , in stackoverflow nothing says "Thank you" as an upvote  and an accepted answer mark :) :)  You're welcome.

Comment: Fine happy xD? i was going to give you, just waiting for a reply :) (Therefor Cesar's upvote too ^^)

Comment: pooooooints... ppppappOOOOooooOOOooointss... happy = true :P I warn you, these things are addictive, run while you can!!! ruuuun, rrrUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnnnN!